# How to unbind h and l in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm learning vim and I would like to unbind **h** and **l** (left and right movements).

What should I include in my **.vimrc**?

Note: By doing that I'm forcing myself to use w, W, b, B, e, and other movements to move horizontally.

Comment: Not an answer, but sometimes you do legit need to move left or right one character at a time.  And pressing h a few times isn't the end of the world, trying to find the exact combination of jumps to get somewhere is usually slower than just moving to one character at a time.

Comment: Planning on using other movements to do that. Example is f<character>

Comment: If you're right next to the character, that's more keystrokes than h ;)

Comment: FYI for `h/l` you can still use `<BS>`/`<Space>` in emergency. It would be neat if a singly pressed `hjkl` could be disabled while say `5j` could still be enabled.

Comment: @progo Didn't knew that! That is genius, feels better to use space if I need to adjust my cursor one character than l. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nop to suppress the effect of a command:

```
nnoremap h <NOP>
nnoremap l <NOP>
```

Comment: nnoremap stands for normal non-recursive remap?

Comment: Exactly! For mapping in visual and select mode replace the first n by a v

Answer (score 0):

You could study/enhance the ["dogmatic.vim: Arrow keys are heretical"](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3571) plugin, which not only disables the keys but also displays a message to remind you. You would need to duplicate the following lines:

```
noremap <silent> <right> <Esc>:call dogmatic#TrackArrowPress('right')<cr>
noremap <silent> <left> <Esc>:call dogmatic#TrackArrowPress('left')<cr>
noremap <silent> <up> <Esc>:call dogmatic#TrackArrowPress('up')<cr>
noremap <silent> <down> <Esc>:call dogmatic#TrackArrowPress('down')<cr>
```

If you follow this approach you could consider providing a patch/pull request to the plugin author, possible by creating an option which allows the plugin user to enable/disable your modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I don't already use arrows. That's a neat plugin.